How does streaming work in OpenAI's APIs?
I have a basic understanding of how event streams work. I am currently converting langchain code to directly use OpenAI's API and I have a piece of code I am a bit confused about.
def stream_message(
    messages
):
    client = OpenAI(api_key=settings.OPENAI_API_KEY)
    response = client.chat.completions.create(messages=messages, model="gpt-4o", temperature=0.5, stream=True, stop=None)
    return response

response = stream_message(messages,)

for sse in response:
            content = sse_chunk.choices[0].delta.content
            # some other stuff

What I'm confused about is that the python function stream_message is executed once and then is iterated. When I put a breakpoint under the initial API call and inspect it, it gives me the entire response from GPT. Is this really streaming data back? How does this work if I call the function once and I iterate the response value underneath? How is the response getting updated as I iterate the object if it really is streaming a response back?

https://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html

@Ry- Am I understanding this correctly? The OpenAI API call is returning a Stream object which is a generator. As we iterate that generator object, we are getting the next chunk of data and the response object is getting the updated data as a stream as an independent process?

When you use stream=True in the OpenAI API call, it streams data back incrementally. The response object is an iterable that yields chunks of data as they are generated.
API call:
response = client.chat.completions.create(messages=messages, model="gpt-4o", temperature=0.5, stream=True)

Iteration:
for sse_chunk in response:
    content = sse_chunk.choices[0].delta.content
    # some other stuff


As we iterate, is it just polling the response object? There is an SSE pattern that openai uses which is a 1-way protocol I think.

yes, SSE is a standardized way to use http streams (in http/1 it was called chunked encoding).
